# Strategy to open order at end of day and close order at open of the next day on the daily chart

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

This is a snippet of the script. The strategy is meant for the daily chart and each bar is for the day. The script will look to see if DI+ or DI- is on top. If DI+ is on top, enter a long position at the end of the day and close the position at the open of the next day. If DI- is on top, open a short position and close the position at the open of the next day. I've gotten close, but "process_orders_on_close" closes the position using the close price instead of the open.

I'm stump and not even sure if this is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
@version=4

strategy("Sam's Strategy", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = true,initial_capital=10000)


plot(plus, color = color.green, title="plusDI")
plot(minus, color = color.red, title="minusDI")

overallLong = bool(na)
overallShort = bool(na)


Decision = bool(na)
//ADX enters zone between DMI for the first time
//  if green above red, go calls
Decision := if plus > minus
    Decision := true
    overallShort := na
    overallLong := true
//  if red above green, go puts
else if minus > plus
    Decision := true
    overallLong := na
    overallShort := true
else
    na

strategy.close_all()
//strategy part

if (afterStartDate and overallLong)
    strategy.entry("GG-EL", long=true)
if (afterStartDate and overallShort)
    strategy.entry("GG-ES", strategy.short)
```

Comment: What if adopt the strategy to work on 1/2/4h timeframe (several bars in one day)? In this case you can entry on one bar and exit on other one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the signals are based on the daily candle.